Color-Coded Time Series Plot Based on Value Sign
I have a dataframe containing positive,negative and zero values.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-1, 3, 9, 5, 0, -1, -1],
                  'B': [4, -5, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6],
                  'C': [7, 5, -3,-1, 5, 9, 3],
                  'D': [-3, 6, 7, 4, 0, -2, -1],
                 'date':['01-02-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-03-2021', '01-05-2021', '01-10-2021', '01-03-2022', '01-08-2022']})

# make sure the time column is actually time format
df1['date']=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

# set time as the index
df1.set_index('date',inplace=True)

df1

I want to show the month and year on the X-axis, there should be 4 scatterplots and I want the markers (i.e. scatter circles)  to be 'red' for the negative values in the corresponding month/year,'green' for positive and yellow for zero, which I have tried to do with a list comprehension statement below.
# to condition by colour
kcolors = ['green' if s>0 else 'red' if s<0 else 'yellow' for s in df1]  # this gives a  TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
# I have also tried
# kcolors = ['#00ff41' if s>0 else '#65000B' if s<0 else '#F5D300' for s in df1]

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df1.plot(kind='scatter', marker='o', color=kcolors, ax=ax)

ax.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45, ha='center')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

How can I achieve this?

The original post requested the use of a line plot with markers but was changed because a comment suggested that wasn't possible. The following answer color-codes the markers, and the line from its marker.
Tested in python v3.12.3, pandas v2.2.2, matplotlib v3.8.4.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [-1, 3, 9, 5, 0, -1, -1],
    'B': [4, -5, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6],
    'C': [7, 5, -3, -1, 5, 9, 3],
    'D': [-3, 6, 7, 4, 0, -2, -1],
    'date': ['01-02-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-03-2021', '01-05-2021', '01-10-2021', '01-03-2022', '01-08-2022']
})

# Convert the date column to datetime format
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

# Set the date column as the index
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Create a 2x2 subplot grid
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 10))
axs = axs.flatten()  # Flatten the 2x2 array of axes for easy iteration

# Loop through each column and its corresponding subplot axis
for ax, col in zip(axs, df1.columns):
    # Loop through each pair of consecutive points
    for i in range(len(df1)-1):
        x = df1.index[i:i+2]  # Get the two consecutive dates
        y = df1[col].iloc[i:i+2]  # Get the two consecutive values for the current column
        
        # Determine the color based on the value
        if y.iloc[0] > 0:
            color = 'green'
        elif y.iloc[0] < 0:
            color = 'red'
        else:
            color = 'yellow'
        
        # Plot the segment with the determined color
        ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', color=color)
    
    # Set the title of the subplot to the column name
    ax.set_title(f'{col}')
    
    # Rotate and format the x-axis dates
    ax.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45, ha='center')

# Adjust layout to prevent overlap
plt.tight_layout()

# Display the plot
plt.show()


Similar Questions:

color line by "value"
How to plot one line in different colors
Different color for line depending on corresponding values


If you want each of these plots on a separate Axes instance, you will need to create our layout manually, then iterate over the columns and plot them separately.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'A': [-1, 3, 9, 5, 0, -1, -1],
        'B': [4, -5, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6],
        'C': [7, 5, -3,-1, 5, 9, 3],
        'D': [-3, 6, 7, 4, 0, -2, -1],
    },
    index=pd.to_datetime(
        ['01-02-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-03-2021', '01-05-2021', '01-10-2021', '01-03-2022', '01-08-2022']
    )
)

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['yellow'], name='my_cmap')
cmap.set_under('red')
cmap.set_over('green')
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=-1e-9, vmax=1e-9)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax, (name, col) in zip(axes.flat, df1.items()):
    path = ax.scatter(
        col.index, col, c=col, label=name, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
    )
    ax.set_title(name, loc='left', size='x-large', weight='bold')
    ax.set_facecolor('gainsboro') # yellow is very hard to see on a white background

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45, ha='right')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()



You can use a ListedColormap and set_extremes() to define your colours and use vmin and vmax to define when those extremes should be used. E.g.,
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [-1, 3, 9, 5, 0, -1, -1],
        'B': [4, -5, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6],
        'C': [7, 5, -3,-1, 5, 9, 3],
        'D': [-3, 6, 7, 4, 0, -2, -1],
        'date': ['01-02-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-03-2021', '01-05-2021', '01-10-2021', '01-03-2022', '01-08-2022']
    }
)

# make sure the time column is actually time format
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

# set time as the index
df1.set_index('date',inplace=True)

# create the colormap with yellow and add green/red for extremes
my_colors = ["yellow"]
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(my_colors, name="my_cmap")
cmap.set_extremes(under="green", over="red")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# use vmin/vmax to define values under/over which the "extremes" will be used
ax.scatter(df1.index, df1["A"], c=df1["A"], cmap=cmap, vmin=-1e-6, vmax=1e-6)

ax.figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45, ha='center')


Can you tell which Matplotlib version are you using? I'm getting AttributeError: 'ListedColormap' object has no attribute 'set_extremes' with my version 3.3.4.

In that version you'll have to set the under and over values separately, i.e., cmap.set_under("green") and cmap.set_over("red") https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap
